# Composer removing random files from package after installation

Tags: php, composer-php, mpdf

this is the console output (shortened a bit):

```
λ composer require mpdf/mpdf
Using version ^6.1 for mpdf/mpdf
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing setasign/fpdi (1.6.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mpdf/mpdf (v6.1.3): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Removed 31 files or directories.
```

Why the hell is there the last line? When I then try to use mPDF in my project, it doesn't work (file not found), because most of the mPDF source files are really missing in the directory. When I lookup in the composer cache, all the files are there, so composer probably installs all the files and then randomly removes 31 files or directories. Why? And how can I fix this? I tried using a newer version of the package, same problem.

Composer version: 1.5.2 (just updated)
Also cache cleared just before the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is caused by [dg/composer-cleaner](https://github.com/dg/composer-cleaner) package I believe you have installed.

Uninstall the package and it will stop removing files.

Or, you can setup the package to ignore mpdf vendor directory as per package README:

You can also specify paths to be ignored via composer.json. As far as I am aware by glancing into the code, there is no way to ignore a whole package, so you have to specify all files and directories in root directories explicitly.

```
{
    "require": {
        "dg/composer-cleaner": "^1.1",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1"
    },
    "extra": {
        "cleaner-ignore": {
            "setasign/fpdi": [
                "fpdi_bridge.php",
                "pdf_parser.php"
            ],
            "mpdf/mpdf": [
                "collations",
                "font",
                "includes",
                "patterns",
                "qrcode",
                "tmp",
                "ttfontdata",
                "ttfonts",
                ".gitignore",
                "compress.php",
                "config.php",
                "config_fonts-distr-without-OTL.php",
                "config_fonts.php",
                "config_lang2fonts.php",
                "config_script2lang.php",
                "graph.php",
                "graph_cache",
                "iccprofiles",
                "lang2fonts.css",
                "mpdf.css",
                "MpdfException.php",
                "phpunit.xml",
                "progbar.css",
                "Tag.php"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

That should be a lot easier with mPDF 7.x (now in beta) which has a much saner project directory structure.

Comment: Bingo! Is that a bug or a feature? :D

Comment: Dunno. Probably a missed not-so-much-corner case.